# Rest Traversal Neo4j java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, spring, rest, neo4j, graph-traversal

This is my first application on neo4j, i like to use the traversal API for better performance and the ease of use, however i was stumped when i looked at the rest traversal most of the operations are not implemented, i am using  spring-data-neo4j-rest ( 3.1.2) neo4j kernal and core version os 2.0
 Ex. from Resttraversal Src ( only two evaluators are implemented) Am i using the right version if not which version supports more of this one

```
 public RestTraversalDescription evaluator(PathEvaluator evaluator) {
        if (evaluator == Evaluators.all()) return add("return_filter",toMap("language","builtin", "name","all"));
        if (evaluator == Evaluators.excludeStartPosition()) return add("return_filter",toMap("language","builtin", "name","all_but_start_node"));
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only builtin paths supported");
    }


 @Override
    public TraversalDescription expand(PathExpander<?> expander) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public <STATE> TraversalDescription expand(PathExpander<STATE> expander, InitialStateFactory<STATE> initialState) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

NEED HELP and i feel i wasted more than a day browsing for solution....

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to get maximum performance for your traversals would be to use [unmanaged extensions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) that internally use the [Traversal API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal.html).

You bascially write a Java (or Groovy/Clojure/Scala/... ) class using JAX-RS annotations. Your code gets packaged as a jar and deployed to Neo4j's `plugins` directory. The annotated methods become new REST endpoints to your Neo4j server.

REST traversals as you intended to use them are a rather old and not widely used feature within the product.

Comment: Thanks Stefan ! Let me try. However even if the  is internally using the Traversal API, the programmer has to manage how the traversal should happen based on the path evaluation, most of the methods in the RestTraversal are not implemented..how do i solve this..or do you have sample that would do a simple traversal using the unmanaged extension or any API docs that could help?

Answer (score 0):

Since i upgraded to Neo4j 2.3, i used cypher as part of the unmanaged extension. Seems working efficiently now also achieving the pattern matching flexibility that cypher provides